# Can't get the source code from a page when not typing the name manually

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, urllib, urllib3

*(first post on stackoverflow)*

I'm trying to download the source code from that page `"https://nyaa.crystalyx.net/search?q=Kuzu+no+Honkai"` using `urllib3` on `python 3.7.1`.

I created the following function to save source code in a file:

```
def get_source_code(url : str):

    print(url,len(url))
    os.system("pause")

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', url)
    content = str(r.data)
    #print(content)

    #Saves the source_code in a file
    source_code = open("source_code.txt","w+")
    for letter in content:
        source_code.write(letter)
    source_code.close()

    #Saves the elements of the source code in a list of element splitted by "\n" then deletes the initial file
    source_code = open("source_code.txt","r+")
    content = (source_code.readline()).split("\\n")
    source_code.close()
    #os.system("pause")
    os.remove("source_code.txt")

    #Creates a new file containing the source_code correctly displayed
    source_code = open("source_code.txt","w+")
    for element in content:
        source_code.write(element + '\n')
    source_code.close()
```

Everything works well when I call my function like this:

`get_source_code("https://nyaa.crystalyx.net/search?q=Kuzu+no+Honkai")`

***(you can check the output here https://pastebin.com/SBumCH3b)***

So I tried calling my function in a more user-friendly way by using `input()`

```
to_download = str(input("Enter the name of the anime you wanna download: "))
to_download = to_download.replace(" ","+")
to_download = str("https://nyaa.crystalyx.net/search?q=") + str(to_download)
get_source_code(to_download)
```

This ends up giving me a very different and uncomplete source code inside my file
***(you can check the output here https://pastebin.com/bq0dqeZw)***

I've already checked if the two strings given to `get_source_code()` are the same and have the same lenght

If anyone can help me it'd be cool.
Thanks.

Comment: What did you enter?

Comment: As I said, I entered the first time (when it worked)

`get_source_code("https://nyaa.crystalyx.net/search?q=Kuzu+no+Honkai")`



then the second time (where it didn t work)
`get_source_code(to_download)`

Comment: Before calling the function, I have `print(to_download) = https://nyaa.crystalyx.net/search?q=Kuzu+no+Honkai` so I don't get the problem

Comment: In cmd I wrote `Kuzu no Honkai`

Answer (score 1):

It's spelled wrong in your second query hence the mistake. In the first screen shot you paste the query is

```
required type="search" value="Kuzu no Honkai">
```

In the second query where you take an input it gets spelled *slightly* different

```
required type="search" value="Kozu no Honkai">
```

Notice how it says *Kozu* instead of *Kuzu*. Looks like you spelled it wrong entering it.